# Android BLE read value for characteristics is null

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am building an Android App for communication with  BLE hardware device.
Now I am able to fetch customServices and characteristics successfully and can read properties as well.
But the main issue is
        1) -it returns characteristics.getProperties() as 26 but expected answer should be WRITE/READ?NOTIFY.
       2) -while reading Value for a characteristics it reutns null 
         (byte[] value=characteristics.getValue();).

Hardware device is sending "CALL" string as a value over BLE and I need to fetch it in byte[].
Please any help is appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) This is correct, and you are actually receiving what you want. Check constants on this page: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html

2) Try characteristic.getStringValue();
OR this might be helpful
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#readCharacteristic(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic)